# Xaml - Group Style with extra heading

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml

I have been trying all day to get this working. I am at the final post.
I am using group descriptors via a collectionviewsource and am trying to manipulate the header.

```
<GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,5"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
              <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <Border Height="Auto" Margin="4,2,2,0" CornerRadius="5" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FF9B9595" Background="#FFFDF9CA">
                        <StackPanel >
                            <TextBlock Foreground="Firebrick" Text="{Binding Path=Name,StringFormat=dd/MM/yyyy}" FontSize="13" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>                                               
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Items[0].NameOfDay}"/>
                            <ItemsPresenter/>
                        </StackPanel>               
                    </Border>                                           
                </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
    <GroupStyle.Panel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel></WrapPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GroupStyle.Panel>
</GroupStyle>
```

I am looking to get the header to show the date (which its grouped by) and the Day of the week (which is in the recordset)
You can see my attempt above.
Thanks in advance
Scott

Comment: In what way does your code fail? Do you know that you can output the name of the weekday from a DateTime by using the 'dddd' formater (or 'ddd' if you need the abbreviated form)? If you need any language else than English be sure to set the applicable culture as WPF will default to English culture for DateTime.  
    
    `<TextBlock Text="{Binding DateProperty, StringFormat=dddd}">`

Comment: Thanks. It's about adding new items in that stack panel and them being seen. For  example adding an image. The DayOfWeek field does not appear so I assume within the header I need to do soemthing else. scott